# Regex replace remove strings

Tags: regex, abap

I've got any string:

> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I've got lets say 3 strings i would like to replace:

- abc
- def
- ghi

An example string could look like this:

> xxxxxxxxxxxabcyyyydefzz

The desired output would be:

> xxxxxxxxxxxyyyyzz

The following regexp works fine:

```
^(.*)(?:abc|def|ghi)(.*)$ replacing with $1$2
```

But if the input string does not contain any of these 3 strings, the pattern does not match and the output is empty.

How can I avoid that behaviour?

Comment: Language is ABAP NW 7.31

Comment: The suggested pattern does not work at all. @Tushar

Answer (score 2):

Just don't match the rest of the string in groups. Simply replace

```
(?:abc|def|ghi)
```

with empty string.

Comment: Ok but how does the replace statement has to look like?

Comment: @thefiloe, the same as your current statement, except empty string instead of `$1$2`.